# R TIME-TO-EVENT

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am new to R (started to teach myself last week) and new to this forum.

I am working on a dataset where I need to determine the time-to-event. I have three variables (Drug, Patient and Date) and I need to work out the time difference for each patient when they switch drugs. Also of note is that a patient could move from Drug A to Drug B and back to Drug A, so date sequence is of importance.

I currently have this data is a dataframe called "data"

```
data <-data.frame(Drug=sample(c("Drug A","Drug B", "Drug C", "Drug D", "Drug E"),100,
replace=TRUE),PAT=rep(1:10,each=10),Date=sample(seq(as.Date('2003/01/01'), 
as.Date('2016/01/01'), by="day"), 100))
data<-data[order(data$PAT,data$Date),]
```

Any help would be great, and I'm sorry I haven't had things clear or deviated from this forum's protocol...

The output required would be the proportion of patients who switched from their first drug to their second drug (and also 2nd to 3rd, 3rd to 4th, and lastly 4th to 5th) at each time point...
So at time 0 (when the first record of each patient exists), 100% of patients have not switched, the next row would be day 2 (where 99% of patients may not have switched), then day 3, then day 4 etc.

Cheers

Comment: Please use dput to show the example data and not as an image (as we can't copy from the image for testing).  Also, an expected output should be great

Comment: Do you only care about the first switch or should there be indicators for those after as well (ie do you want percent who have switched at least once or number of switches that have occurred)?  If a patient started on Drug A at t0, then switched to B at t1, and finally back to A at t2 at would the time series for that patient look like t0 = 0, t1 = 1, t2 = 0 to indicate they are back on the first drug, or t0 = 0, t1 = 1, t2 = 1 to indicate they switched once starting at t1 or t0 = 0, t1 = 1, t2 = 2 to indicate the total number of switches the patient made?

Comment: Two different questions have been posed: one; time intervals to switching which would be a subject-specific set of results, versus two; proportions of patients switching in each daily interval which could be a  a drug-by interval result or just a by-interval result . They will not be the same and it is entirely unclear which one is desired because of the discrepant descriptions and a failure to work through a  examples by hand and provide an exact answer for a few cases.

Comment: Maybe part of your investigation (referred to as part 2 by @42 above) could benefit from the use of the TraMineR package in R. http://mephisto.unige.ch/pub/TraMineR/doc/TraMineR-Users-Guide.pdf I found this quite useful for assessing state transition distributions, which in your case would be drug type.

Comment: As follow-up to Big Old Dave's useful comment, he could have referenced the CRAN package info at: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TraMineR/index.html

Comment: He could. Mea culpa!

Comment: Hey guys, WOW! thanks for all the input, this has been very helpful. Barker, what I am looking for is the time to switch (ie. First line therapy, second line therapy, third line therapy), so Drug A maybe first line and third line therapy. So there are several analyses, but the primary analysis would be the time on firstline therapy (ie the time til first switch). The primary outcome would be a Kaplan-Meier curve (sorry I thought that was self-evident with the title of this post, but is isnt) and whether I can capture censoring or not is a plus. I will look into TraMineR and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

....an answer to 'part deux' if I've understood the intent correctly. Note I've reduced the number of dates from 100 to 10, to get the sequences contemporaneous.

```
library(TraMineR)

data <- data.frame(Drug=sample(c("Drug A","Drug B", "Drug C", "Drug D", "Drug E"),100,replace=TRUE),
              PAT=rep(1:10,each=10),
              Date=sample(seq(as.Date('2003/01/01'),as.Date('2016/01/01'), by="day"), 10))

data <- data[order(data$PAT,data$Date),]

data2 <- reshape(data, idvar="PAT", timevar="Date", direction="wide")

data.seq <- seqdef(data2,2:11)

seqiplot(data.seq)
seqdplot(data.seq)
```

The last plot function giving.... [image]